# Delete Computer Object in AD with Powershell?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, scripting, powershell, deployment

I am able to use the native add-computer cmdlet to join a computer to a domain, but it seems that this cmdlet fails if the systems already exists in AD, and you are trying to add it to a different domain.

I would like to delete the existing object with powershell. Is this possible without loading the Active Directory Module? I am doing all this as part of system deployment, and don't want to have to load any additional windows features.

EDIT:
This will need run in a way where I can pass credentials to the command. It will be run in the context of a local user.

Comment: netdom will let you pass creds.

Comment: How are you imaging these computers? If you're using an unattend file, there's a specific field for domain join that is run during the `Specialize` pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using DSRM CLI-tool, which is awesome.

[DSRM description and usage examples - Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731865%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

NOTE: it's not available on W7, but *.exe files can be extracted from Windows Server 2008 machine.

[How can i get DSRM.exe to work without installing RSAT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/is/winserverDS/thread/f6aff089-46bb-4371-8068-57c291507088)

Comment: dsrm would mean that you have the active dir tools loaded.

Comment: Yes, right you are. Edited answer with an update.

Comment: don't think I'd waste my time with dsrm in this case since netdom is builtin.

Comment: Are you sure netdom is built-in on W7 OS? Tried viewing help for just now on my machine, but got not recognized message.
It's built in on Windows Server family OS 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: lol you maybe right, in my case it must be there due to the imaging process that we use.

Comment: copying dsrm, dsquery, dsmove and associated .mui's seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

use `net computer \\computername /del`
or use `netdom remove` which will allow you to specify what domain.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788074(v=ws.10).aspx

Looks like `netdom.exe` is not native to Windows 7 so just add it to your image.